# Attempting to stop wav file from playing after pressing the Jbutton a second time, but it doesn't stop

Tags: java, swing

The program is supposed to play the fitnessgram pacer test when a user presses the button.  One the button is pressed a second time, the audio stops.  Upon pressing the button again the program should then start playing the test from the begining again.  Here is my code:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class aMeme extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public JButton button;
    public boolean check;
    public boolean audio;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        if (check == true){
            BufferedImage img = null;
            try{
                img = ImageIO.read(newFile("C:/Users/kebrobst18/Downloads/Fitnessgram.png"));
            } catch (IOException e){
            }
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        button=new JButton();
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        button.setText("Start/Stop"); 
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
        audio = false;
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){    
        check = true;
        repaint();
        try{
            URL fg = new URL("http://sendeyo.com/up/8658f011a4c712b5da42f74af77729fe.wav");
            Clip fitness = AudioSystem.getClip();
            AudioInputStream gram = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fg);
            fitness.open(gram);
            if (audio == false){
                fitness.start();
                audio = true;
            } else if (audio == true){
                fitness.stop();
                audio = false;
            }
        } catch (LineUnavailableException f){
        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException f) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        aMeme x = new aMeme();
        x.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please improve the format of your code for readability 2) Please tell more details of your problem, what errors or misbehaviors you see, what the code does 3) Surely all your catch blocks aren't empty, are they? That's mighty dangerous programming if so.

Comment: 4) Don't draw within a JFrame's paint method. Do it within a JPanel's paintComponent method 5) Call the super's painting method within your own painting method 6) **Never** read in a file from within a painting method

Comment: 7) You look to be using resources that you're not closing. 8) Are you experiencing a Swing threading issue? e.g., is your entire program freezing?  **Edit**: I've tried to improve your code formatting for you.

Comment: Right now the only problem with my code is that it does not stop the audio when the button is pressed again.  Other than that is works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Your audio objects are local to the ActionPerformed method. When the button is pressed a 2nd time, **completely new audio objects are created**, and calling stop on them won't have any beneficial effect at all since you're not stopping the audio object that is currently playing. Make the important audio objects into instance fields of your class.  In particular, the fitness variable needs to be made an instance field.

---

Other unrelated but important issues are as per my comments:

- Again, in the future, please improve the format of your posted code for readability
- Don't leave your catch blocks empty, and at least print the stacktrace. Otherwise you're flying blind.
- Don't draw within a JFrame's paint method and don't leave out the super call within your painting method. Instead paint within a JPanel's paintComponent method, and call the super's paintComponent method on its first line,
- Never read in a file from within a painting method as this is unnecessary and cuts into the perceived responsiveness of your program.
- Close resources when you're done using them.

Comment: I'm trying change the important audio objects into instance fields, however, they all throw exceptions and I am unsure of the best way to catch or declare the exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example of replaying the same audio file:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;

class SoundTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL urlToSound = new URL("file:c:/java/gun1.wav");
//    URL urlToSound = new URL("file:c:/java/flyby1.wav");
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(urlToSound);
    final Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(ais);
    JButton button = new JButton("Bird Sounds");
    button.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          clip.setFramePosition(0);
          clip.start();
        }
      } );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, button);
  }
}
```